# How to use a dynamically generated value in a template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, templates, data-binding

I have a custom form application written in AngularJS and now I need to use the data from the form in a template.  But nothing I've tried seems to work.

I am creating a custom directive like this...

```
.directive('dynamicModel', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        'link': function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamicModel, function(dynamicModel) {
                if (attrs.ngModel == dynamicModel || !dynamicModel) return;

                element.attr('ng-model', dynamicModel);
                if (dynamicModel == '') {
                    element.removeAttr('ng-model');
                }

                // Unbind all previous event handlers, this is
                // necessary to remove previously linked models.
                element.unbind();
                $compile(element)(scope);
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

This is attached to a form element like this..

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="field in customForm.fields">
<label>{{field.displayname}}
       <input class="form-control" type="{{field.type}}" name={{field.variable}} dynamic-model="field.databind" placeholder="{{field.variable}}" required="{{field.isRequired}}"></label></div>
```

This part works great, the field is now 2 way bound to the input form.
However when I later tried to use the same method to show the value in a report computed from the form, I get "field.databind" or at best the resolved databind field name such as "currentUser.name" rather than the value, e.g. "devlux"

I've tried

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="field in customForm.fields">
<p>{{field.name}} = {{field.databind}}</p>
Also
<p dynamicModel="field.databind"></p>
</div>
```

Nothing works unless I put it into an input element, which isn't what I'm trying to do here.

The dynamic model code was pulled off someone elses answer to a question about creating dynamic form elements, and honestly I think it's just a step beyond my comprehension.  But assuming that "field.databind" will always be a string literal containing the name of an inscope model, how on earth do I access it in a normal template?

Comment: Yes, apologies I was unaware I needed to formally "accept" the answer.  I'm a total noob here.  tasseKATT's answer was correct and works flawlessly.

Comment: It's fine :) Always preferable to accept the answer you find to be correct so the question doesn't remaing "unsolved". If an answer doesn't work for you it's also good to leave a comment underneath it to let the writer know. That's why I was asking, to follow up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{field.databind}}` will be evaluated against the current `$scope` and will result in whatever `$scope.field.databind` is, for example the string `currentUser.name`.

Angular has no way of knowing that `currentUser.name` isn't the string you want, but actually another expression that you want to evaluate.

To evaulate it again you will need to add a function to your `$scope` that uses the `$parse` service.

For example:

```
$scope.parseValue = function (value) {
  return $parse(value)($scope);
};
```

In HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="field in customForm.fields">
  <p>{{field.displayname}} = {{parseValue(field.databind)}}</p>
</div>
```

The argument that gets passed to `parseDynamicValue` will for example be `currentUser.name`. Then it uses the `$parse` service to evaulate the expression against the current `$scope`, which will result in for example `devlux`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/iPsGvfqU0FSgQWGwi21W?p=preview